# Query Regarding Android AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm looking to implement a CRUD application on Android 2.3.3 as a learning PoC using SQLite database. For now, I've put in a search activity containing the search form, and a search results activity(under construction). I'm  using an AsyncTask to process the db access, and want to display this data on the next activity.

Currently, I'm launching the results activity from the `onPostExecute` method, and the results seem to be showing fine, but doesn't this launch the new activity in the second thread(created for AsyncTask)?

If that is the case, how do I return data back to the UI thread, and launch the results activity from there?

Please feel free to ask for clarification, I'm not a frequent poster, so my posts tend to be a little half-baked, at times.

Debojit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) is in the background thread. [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) is in the UI thread. That's the beauty of AsyncTask: set it up in the UI thread, it does the high-latency work, such as file and network access, in the background thread, and then it responds back in the UI thread with onPostExecute.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot. A further query: should I be using `Service` and/or `ContentProvider` for this?

Comment: Your use case justifies a ContentProvider but not a Service.

Comment: In my use case, is it recommended(performance-wise) to use a `ContentProvider`, or do I leave it as a DAO(my current implementation) invoked from `doInBackground`? Sorry if this sounds a little obtuse.

Comment: If your version works, and it's fast enough, and you don't plan on expanding on the DB access, then leave well enough alone. Otherwise, CP is the right way to do it.